# Array co-variance in C# generic list

Tags: c#, generics, abstract, covariance, ilist

I have an example where I want an abstract class interface to return something like this

```
abstract class AnimalProcessor {
    public abstract IList<Animal> ProcessResults();
}
```

Then the concrete examples

```
class GiraffeProcessor : AnimalProcessor {
    public override IList<Animal> ProcessResults() {
        return new List<Giraffe>();
    }
}

class LionProcessor : AnimalProcessor {
    public override IList<Animal> ProcessResults() {
        return new List<Lion>();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the concrete classes need to have the same signature to override the `ProcessResults()` method so they need to return an `IList<Animal>`, however the ACTUAL data I want to return is an `IList<Lion>`, `IList<Giraffe>` etc, but then the calling code has to do

```
GiraffeProcessor processor = new GiraffeProcessor();
IList<Animal> results = processor.GetResults();
```

Which does not give me an Ilist which is what I want.

Problems

1) Above code does not compile. The giraffeProcessor has to return a concrete `List<Animal>`, you can populate it with `Giraffe` objects but the object type you construct to return has to be `List<Animal>`. Not ideal.

2) When you return the results, you can only get an `IList<Animal>`, not `IList<Giraffe>`. I have tried casting explicitly to `IList<Giraffe>` with 
`IList<Giraffe> results = (IList<Giraffe>) processor.GetResults();`
which gives a runtime error, presumably because the object returned is NOT an `IList<Giraffe>`, it is an `IList<Animal>` which CONTAINS `Giraffe` objects.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong here with my design as Im a bit stumped as to the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: What purpose does having a blank IList serve that having a typed IList doesn't serve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
abstract class AnimalProcessor<T> where T : Animal {
    public abstract IList<T> ProcessResults();
}

class GiraffeProcessor : AnimalProcessor<Giraffe> {
    public override IList<Giraffe> ProcessResults() {
        return new List<Giraffe>();
    }
}

class LionProcessor : AnimalProcessor<Lion> {
    public override IList<Lion> ProcessResults() {
        return new List<Lion>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Just the solution I was looking for, wasn't aware of the declaration of Inherited parent classes passing in a generic type like that. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

You could resolve this by declaring AnimalProcessor with a generic type constraint, e.g.

```
public abstract class AnimalProcessor<T> where T : Animal 
{    
    public abstract IList<T> ProcessResults(); 
}
```

If that doesnt work, you could use the LINQ Cast operator, for example:

```
public class GiraffeProcessor : AnimalProcessor 
{     
    public override IList<Animal> ProcessResults() 
    {         
        return new List<Giraffe>().Cast<Animal>();
    } 
}
```

Or, store the list internally as Animal but add Giraffe's to it, e.g.

```
public class GiraffeProcessor : AnimalProcessor 
{     
    private List<Giraffe> _innerList = new List<Giraffe>();
    public override IList<Animal> ProcessResults() 
    {         
        return new List<Animal>(innerList );        } 
}
```

Best regards,

Comment: The standard `Cast<T>()` method will return an `IEnumerable<T>`, not an `IList<T>`

Comment: Yes, very true. calling .Cast<T>().ToList() isn't very efficient. I'd favour generic typed base class first, or second storing the innerlist as a different type. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C# 4.0, you can ask yourself whether the processor should return `IEnumerable<T>` rather than `IList<T>`.  If the answer is "yes", then you can profit from covariance:

```
abstract class AnimalProcessor { 
    public abstract IEnumerable<Animal> ProcessResults(); 
} 

class GiraffeProcessor : AnimalProcessor { 
    public override IEnumerable<Animal> ProcessResults() { 
        return new List<Giraffe>(); 
    } 
} 

class LionProcessor : AnimalProcessor { 
    public override IEnumerable<Animal> ProcessResults() { 
        return new List<Lion>(); 
    } 
}
```

You have a couple of advantages here.  First, you could implement these as iterator blocks:

```
class GiraffeProcessor : AnimalProcessor { 
    public override IEnumerable<Animal> ProcessResults() { 
        yield break;
    } 
}
```

Second, and less trivially, you allow the client code to decide what kind of collection to dump the animals into -- if any.  For example, consider that the consumer might want a `LinkedList<Animal>`:

```
var animals = new LinkedList<Animal>(animalProcessor.ProcessResults());
```

Or consider that the client might need only to iterate the sequence:

```
foreach (var animal in animalProcessor.ProcessResults())
    { /*... do something ...*/ }
```

In either case, if you were using a `ToList()` call in ProcessResults, you'd be creating a list for nothing.  If the consumer really wants a `List<Animal>`, that can be accomplished very easily:

```
var animals = new List<Animal>(animalProcessor.ProcessResults());
```

Finally, you can also benefit from the generic approach, even if you change the interface type of the method's return value:

```
abstract class AnimalProcessor<T> where T : Animal { 
    public abstract IEnumerable<T> ProcessResults(); 
} 

class GiraffeProcessor : AnimalProcessor<Giraffe> { 
    public override IEnumerable<Giraffe> ProcessResults() { 
        yield break;
    } 
} 

class LionProcessor : AnimalProcessor<Lion> { 
    public override IEnumerable<Lion> ProcessResults() { 
        return Enumerable.Empty<Lion>();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just a question on Lists, I quite like using the List<>.ForEach(a => action()) approach but it seems every time I get an IEnumerable I have to first do .ToList<T>() before doing the .ForEach(). Am I using this wrong?

Comment: Yes.  Your ToList() call allocates an array and copies all the items to it, unneccessarily.  You could trivially implement your own extension method to allow this syntax on `IEnumerable<T>`, but, as Eric Lippert has written, it's philosophically questionable.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx.  (And in a response to a comment on that post, he notes that he is also philosophically troubled by `List<T>.ForEach()`.)